# Вылетает проводник на 7-ке при распечатке пробного листа на расшаренном локально принтере 10-ка

Tags: windows, принтер

Есть 10-ка на которой расшарен принтер локально. Есть комп с 7-кой к ней подключен данный принтер. При печати пробной страницы на 7-ке вылетает Проводник.

Обновления на 10-ке кривые удалил, дрова перенакатывал (то бишь удаление и добавление принтера на 10-ке и 7-ке). Антивирусом проверил обе машины, службы печати перезапускал ничего не помогает.

Comment: Винды - сборки или чистые?

Comment: Сборки скорее всего.

Comment: так а в логах то какие жалобы? должен же код ошибки какой то быть

Comment: Та же проблема, но это что-то с win 10, т.к. ни однин win 7 не может распечатать, а с Win 10 печать без проблем.